# Extending a line which has been plotted non-numerically

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm using MATLAB to plot tangent to a curve using tools in the financial toolbox. I'm trying to extend one of the lines that has been plotted. As the plot involves no actual numerical equations I'm unsure how to do this.

```
plot(PortRisk, PortReturn, 'm', OptRisk, OptReturn, 'x', ...
     0, RisklessRate, 'ksquare',  RiskyRisk, RiskyReturn, 'kdiamond',...
     [0; RiskyRisk], [RisklessRate; RiskyReturn],'r')
xlabel('Portfolio Risk');
ylabel('Portfolio Return ');
title('Efficient Frontier');
grid on
```

The line that I wish to extrapolate on is plotted with the code

```
[RisklessRate; RiskyReturn],'r'
```

Basically the code plots a segment between two points. I wish to extend this line. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please provide some example data.

Comment: Im not sure how to add in example data to an edit but the data used is a 70 by 70 matrix where columns represent asset returns so they are all just numbers around 0 such as [0.00453, -0.00389; 0.00862, 0.0127] would be a 2x2 matrix for a case of 2 assets.

Comment: There's no such thing as "non-numerical plotting" – you have numbers, so its numerical. What you mean is that you don't have an equation describing your numbers. As far as I understand, what you're trying to do here is extrapolation, which is a wildly ill-defined problem. Without having your data, or at least seeing your plot, there's no way to help you.